# How to convert .rpt file to .rdl file

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008, rdl, rpt

I need to convert several .rpt file(crystal reports) to rdl files(ssrs reports).
How to generate .rdl file dynamically? 
Is there any link that will provide all the list of formulas to convert ?

Answer (score 0):

Please study following link which will guide you for converting crystal reports(rpt file) to ssrs reports(rdl files).

[Crystal Reports to SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964127%28SQL.90%29.aspx)